# Enumeration extension methods

Tags: .net, enums, extension-methods, enumeration

In vs2008, is it possible to write an extension methods which would apply to any enumeration.

I know you can write extension methods against a specific enumeration, but I want to be able to every enumeration using a single extension method. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extension method on enumeration, not instance of enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422113/extension-method-on-enumeration-not-instance-of-enumeration)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, just code against the base `Enum` type, e.g.

```
public static void Something(this Enum e)
{
    // code here
}
```

The down-side is you'll probably end up doing some quite nasty stuff like finding the real base type using [`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx), casting, and going down different branches depending on what the base type of the enum is, but you can find some good uses for it (e.g. we have `IsOneOf` and `IsCombinationOf` methods that apply to all enums).

PS: Remember when writing the method that, although ill advised, you can use `float` and `double` as the base types for enums so you'll need some special cases for those as well as unsigned values.

Comment: The examples you gave are exactly what I want to do, even the same name. :)

Comment: @Greg: In which language can you use float and double as the underlying type for an enum? You can't in C# - you get error CS1008: Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong expected

Comment: The only language I know of that supports it is CIL. I haven't actually tried it out to prove it because it seems like a generally bad idea, but see Rico's comment near the bottom here: http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_Type_Design_Guidelines%E2%80%94Enum_Design

Comment: @Luis - No, you need C# 3.0 syntax for extension methods, which isn't supported in VS2005.

Comment: @GregBeech: Are you able to help with this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18145161/175893

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can. The target extenstion type is of type `Enum`. In C#, this would be done as:

```
public static void EnumExtension(this Enum e)
{
}
```

or like this in VB:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub EnumExtension(ByVal s As Enum)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 18):

FYI Here is a great example of an Enum Extension method that I have been able to use.  It implements a case insensitive TryParse() function for enums:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool TryParse<T>(this Enum theEnum, string strType, 
        out T result)
    {
        string strTypeFixed = strType.Replace(' ', '_');
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), strTypeFixed))
        {
            result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), strTypeFixed, true);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
            {
                if (value.Equals(strTypeFixed, 
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            result = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it in the following manner:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public void TestMethod(string StringOfEnum)
{
    TestEnum myEnum;
    myEnum.TryParse(StringOfEnum, out myEnum);
}
```

Here are the two sites that I visited to help come up with this code:

[Case Insensitive TryParse for Enums](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/03/Another-version-for-the-missing-method-EnumTryParse.aspx)

[Extension methods for Enums](http://www.objectreference.net/post/Enum-TryParse-Extension-Method.aspx)

Comment: Just as a footnote, from .net 4 onwards there's Enum.TryParse takes an overload to specify case sensitivity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Here's another example - also nicer IMHO than having to create and initialize a temp variable.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static void ForEach(this Enum enumType, Action<Enum> action)
    {
        foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues(enumType.GetType()))
        {
            action((Enum)type);
        }
    }
}

public enum TestEnum { A,B,C } 
public void TestMethod() 
{
    default(TestEnum).ForEach(Console.WriteLine); 
}
```

Comment: You are still creating a temporary instance of the enum in `default(TestEnum)`, albeit one that is anonymous and immediately up for garbage collection.  It's worth pointing out that extension methods simply do not work without an instance of what is being extended, so the closest that we can get is to instantiate the Type of the enum itself and have an extension method off that type.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422113/extension-method-on-enumeration-not-instance-of-enumeration for an interesting way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 4):

You can also implement conversion method as follows:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ConvertType Convert<ConvertType>(this Enum e)
    {
        object o = null;
        Type type = typeof(ConvertType);

        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            o = Convert.ToInt32(e);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(long))
        {
            o = Convert.ToInt64(e);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(short))
        {
            o = Convert.ToInt16(e);
        }
        else
        {
            o = Convert.ToString(e);
        }

        return (ConvertType)o;
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
int a = MyEnum.A.Convert<int>();
```

Comment: I think every `Enum` implements `IConvertible` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there is a need to convert from one enum to another, based on the name or value of the enum. Here is how it can be done nicely with extension methods:

```
enum Enum1 { One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3 };
enum Enum2 { Due = 2, Uno = 1 };
enum Enum3 { Two, One };

Enum2 e2 = Enum1.One.ConvertByValue<Enum2>();
Enum3 e3 = Enum1.One.ConvertByName<Enum3>();
Enum3 x2 = Enum1.Three.ConvertByValue<Enum3>();

public static class EnumConversionExtensions
{
    public static T ConvertByName<T>(this Enum value)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value));
    }

    public static T ConvertByValue<T>(this Enum value)
    {
        return (T)((dynamic)((int)((object)value)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example of making Enum extension - but this time it returns the input enum type.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> toElementsCollection<T>(this T value) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsEnum == false) throw new Exception("typeof(T).IsEnum == false");

        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
public enum TestEnum { A,B,C };

TestEnum.A.toElementsCollection();
```