# Creating generic extension method for getting list of values' Display Name attribute strings

Tags: c#, generics, enums, extension-methods

I am working on an AngularJS/Asp.Net MVC project and I have several Enums that have `[Display(Name = "Value")]` attributes on their values. I have an extension method that can extract the display name from these that works well enough:

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum value)
{
    Type enumType = value.GetType();
    var enumValue = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
    MemberInfo member = enumType.GetMember(enumValue)[0];

    var attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
    var outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;

    if (((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).ResourceType != null)
    {
        outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
    }

    return outString;
}
```

Converting these Enums to Lists of the display name string values is easy enough:

```
//TODO: there *has* to be a way to do this with a generic or extension method
ViewBag.CurrencyTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.CurrencyType)).Cast<ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.CurrencyType>().Select(v => v.GetDisplayName()).ToList();
ViewBag.PaymentTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.PaymentType)).Cast<ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.PaymentType>().Select(v => v.GetDisplayName()).ToList();
ViewBag.OrgTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.OrganizationType)).Cast<ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.OrganizationType>().Select(v => v.GetDisplayName()).ToList();
ViewBag.States = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.State)).Cast<ProjectName.Web.Models.Common.State>().Select(v => v.GetDisplayName()).ToList();
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I create a common extension method that can create these lists? I tried using generics but adding `where T : Enum` throws an error.

**Update:** based on the type constriction of `where T : struct, IConvertible` from [@Marcel's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391795/creating-generic-extension-method-for-getting-list-of-values-display-name-attri#comment39601961_25391795), and [the function @empi posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392011/1414) I have this static helper function:

```
public static List<string> GetDisplayList<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    }
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<Enum>().Select(v => v.GetDisplayName()).ToList();
}
```

Is there a way to make this an extension method?

Comment: Maybe this can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: Ah, interesting I'll give that a try and report back…

Comment: Extension methods only work with instances, not on types. I mean, how would you even call an extension method on an enum type? I think that generic method is as good as it gets. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422113/extension-method-on-enumeration-not-instance-of-enumeration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need an extension method? A simple static method solves this problem:

```
public static List<string> CreateList<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<Enum>().Select(v => v.GetDisplayName()).ToList();
}
```

And when it comes to generic constraints you should look at [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum) as stated in comments.

Comment: I don't, and I tried something similar but I was trying to `Cast<T>` instead of `Cast<Enum>` this may work, I'll try it…