# Is it possible to write an extension method for a generic Enum type?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Over on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16100/#answer-16104), I found this really nice helper method for parsing a string into a generic Enum value:

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}
```

I'd like to change this from a *helper method* into an *extension method*, but I'm not all that familiar with using generics, so I'm not sure if/how that would work.

I tried this, but as you'll quickly see this code doesn't actually compile:

```
public static T ParseEnum(this T myEnum, string value)
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), value, true);
}
```

And I also tried this, but this doesn't do it either:

```
public static Enum ParseEnum(this Enum myEnum, string value)
{
    return Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), value, true);
}
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm asking about here?

Comment: If you want an extension method for an enum type as opposed to an instance of the enum, that [cannot be done](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2422113/11683).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When writing an extension method, the first thing you need to do is figure out how you want to call it. I.e. *what* are you extending?

In the case of parsing a `string` and returning an `enum` value, the only thing that really makes sense is to extend the `string` class. In that view, this is what the extension method would look like:

```
    public static T ParseEnum<T>(this string text)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text);
    }
```

You would call it like this:

```
Pets pet = "Cat".ParseEnum<Pets>();
```

Another alternative uses type inference, at the cost of a by-reference argument (which I prefer to avoid):

```
    public static void ParseEnum<T>(this string text, out T t)
    {
        t = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text);
    }
```

You would call that like this:

```
Pets pet;

"Cat".ParseEnum(out pet);
```

IMHO this is not as good, even though you get type inference, because you can't use the method call in an expression.

Note that the syntax `Pets.ParseEnum("Cat")` is not going to work, because `Pets` is a type name, not a type instance, and you can extend only based on *instances* of objects. But perhaps the above example is close enough (it's about the same number of characters to type anyway :) )

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! And thanks to all the people who answered. I definitely learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your helper method to Enum<> to make it look like it's extending Enum.

```
/// <summary> Enum Extension Methods </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> type of Enum </typeparam>
public class Enum<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public static T Parse(string input)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), input, true);
    }
}
```

Then use it the same way as the helper method the OP mentioned:

```
var result = Enum<StatusEnum>.Parse("Active");
```

This isn't an extension method. Yet, it shares one of the goals of extension methods. Naming a class close to Enum tries to help discoverability.